# org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService but it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

An attempt was made to call the method org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper.(Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V but it does not exist. Its class, org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper, is available from the following locations:

Comment: Provide more information please like code snippets and what you are trying to do.

Comment: migarating spring 1.5 to 2.1.6 . in process in changed hibernate jar from 5.2 to 5.4. After changing the jar version i am getting following error:An attempt was made to call the method org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V but it does not exist. Its class, org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper, is available from the following locations:project.jar:file://lib/hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/internal/util/xml/XMLHelper.class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a same situation with following dependencies. And I did this.

#### Exclude `hibernate-envers` from `spring-data-envers`.

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
      <version>${version.org.springframework.data}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

And depends on it directly.

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
      <version>${version.org.hibernate}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue migrating from Spring Boot 2.1.3 to 2.1.4,

There are some major changes between Hibernate 5.3 and 5.4, so you need to make sure that all of your dependencies are using this last version.

Solution : update your dependencies to versions using Hibernate 5.4 (In my case I had to update hibernate-jpamodelgen to the last version).

(Maybe you could also use exclusions to prevent your dependencies using the wrong versions : https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)